# Ask permissions for facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

I've developed a facebook app that requires the publish_stream permission to post a dynamically generated image to user's wall.

It functions good, but when a new user wants to use the app, it asks for login and THEN it asks for publish stream permission, and gives them the option to deny that permission and still continue with app.

I'd like to have ONE dialog panel asking for login AND permission at the same time, so if user does not authorize the app to upload photos, then it wont work. I've seen this with other similar apps.

I'm using the following PHP code for this:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
    'scope'             => 'publish_stream'
    )
);

if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

exit;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I'm not talking about users logging in to facebook, but users logging in to use App.

here are some screenshots of the dialogues:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wjCT.jpg

Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' in your app's advanced settings. The new auth dialog uses two screens, this is what everyone will be eventually migrated to.